# Using .keydown() to return div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I'm not really sure if I'm phrasing this correctly, but what I'm trying to do is have a function return a `div`'s id on a `keydown` event.

Say my HTML is:

```
<div class="pad" id="snare" data-key="97"></div>
<div class="pad" id="kick" data-key="98"></div>
```

Essentially I want my JS to do something like this:

```
function handlekeydown(e) {
    console.log("data-key: " + e.keyCode);
    if (e.keycode == $(".pad").data("key")) {
        return this.id
    }
}
```

I could write a `switch` statement with each `keycode` returning a variable with the same name as the id, but that would defeat the purpose of having it in my HTML.

How would I write a function to search a `div` for a `data-key` that would match the `keycode` and then return its id?

Comment: I am afraid returning from an event handler is not similar to returning from a regular function. Where are you using this handler and how are you using it?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I don't see the tag but you're using the syntax with  `$(".pad").data("key")`

Comment: Why not use `querySelector` in the event listener?

Comment: Right now im using : window.addEventListener('keydown',handlekeydown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the question

```
How would I write a function to search a div for a data-key that would match the keycode?
```

You can do it by:

```
function handlekeydown(e) {
    var id;
    var element = $('[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
    if (element.length) {
        id = element[0].id;
    }
}
```

But as mentioned above you can't return the id from the handler, you might wanna call a method from the event handler which uses id.

```
function processId(id) {
    console.log(id);
}

function handlekeydown(e) {
    var element = $('[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
    if (element.length) {
        processId(element[0].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This resolved my issue, but I am not really following the solution. Why use element.length if there is only one thing stored in it?

Comment: there is a chance that there is no div for the matching keyCode, we are bypassing them with that check

Answer (score 0):

A *keydown event* is a keyboard event.

A keydown event will only trigger on the currently **activeElement** of the document.

You need a completely different approach - on which I will come forth with a solution proposal if you decide to change your current approach with something that might actually work for a change.

p.s.: I will update this same reply.